# Losing text header on rotated/scaled iTextSharp pdf, how do I fix?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

When I rotate and scale a pdf, the text header is disappearing but the graphics are fine:

```
pdfContent.AddTemplate(
page,
0, -pScaleHeight, pScaleWidth, 
0, 0, PageSize.LETTER.Height);
```

How do I retain the header text?

Answer (score 0):

So the `page` template contains line art, images, and text.  The text disappears.  The line art and images are fine.  Is that correct?

I suspect the "header text" is an annotation.  PdfImportedPage doesn't copy annotations, unless you're using PdfCopy or PdfSmartCopy instead of PdfWriter or PdfStamper.

It's also possible that the header text is in a Layer (aka Optional Content Group).  Again, PdfWriter and PdfStamper won't handle that well at all.  Pdf[Smart]Copy *might*, but I'm not at all sure.  I don't think the Copies will bring over the doc-level layer information, leading to a broken layer (that might cause it to vanish leaving you with the behavior you're seeing).

Lots of guess-work here.  It's hard to be sure without a sample PDF that demonstrates the behavior.